# Excel Countif Indirect with two requirements in specific cells on separate sheets

Tags: excel, excel-formula, countif

I have a document with 5 sheets

Sheet Names

[image: 1]

Each sheet has titles in that respective language, with a column to identify the genre and a column to identify the Alphabetic order 'A/Z/Any)

In the 'Numbers' sheet I want to be able to automate the calculation of E.G. How many times 'Jazz' appears in Column E and 'Z' appears in Column G of the French Sheet.

[Manual count of Genre and Alphabet requirement in a specfic Language Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DLRgZ.png)

So far in the 'Numbers' sheet I've managed to total how many times the word 'Jazz' appears in each Langugage sheet with the following code: [Count table for the word Jazz found in each sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EVEyY.png)

=COUNTIF(INDIRECT(Sheet_Names[Sheets]),C28)

But I only want it to detect the word Jazz in the E column of each sheet as this is the Genre column, the word Jazz can also be found in my Titles column which it's detecting.

I want to automate the count of Genre and Alphabet requirment in the specific language tabs as seen here: [Manual count of Genre and Alphabet requirement in a specfic Language Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DLRgZ.png)

Image of how the language sheet is set out: [Language Page screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vaHDW.png)

Comment: Does `=COUNTIF(French!E:E,INDIRECT("C28"))` work for you to get only matches on the French sheet's column E

Comment: Yes it did! It's giving me accurate totals for said column in the French sheet. Is there now a means of it doing a count specific to 'count if column G has the following A / Z / Any? 

Thank you :)

Comment: Sorry could you post a picture of one of the language sheets? I don't really understand how they're laid out from the description well enough to help

Comment: absolutely, have added it to end of question

Comment: If you have "language" column in your worksheets, then why do you create a single worksheet per language?

Comment: to make it more user-friendly as many colleagues need to access it and also for deduping purposes. The titles are created in pivot tables and then moved into this final document. French has 8 catalogues and over 20k rows whereas Portuguese has 2 catalogues and only a couple hundred rows